# Set Firebase Cloud Functions Storage file permissions

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-security, busboy

I'm uploading an image from the Firebase Admin. I'm using Firebase Cloud Functions as backend and Busbuy node package to handle the form part. This is the code:

```
getStorage().bucket().file(filePath).save();
```

It's working and now I can see the file is successfully uploaded on the Firebase Console Storage section.

This is the issue:

In the Storage rules I have set:

```
allow read: if false;
```

Which means no one can see the files.

Issue 1: In the Firebase Console if I click on the link, the image opens, but it shouldn't because the permissions are set to deny.

[image: Link I click]

Issue 2: The same way, if I upload the image from the Firebase Admin the same happens.

So I guess if when uploading whether via the Firebase admin or manually in the console these actions override the Storage rules, would be that?

If so, how can I set the **same** Storage rules to the file I upload with the Admin SDK?

NOTE 1: I couldn't use the method `etStorage().bucket().upload(filePath)` because I was unable to create the path, but the other method works. Maybe the `upload method` puts the permissions like I wish... but I'm not sure.

NOTE 2: In the Firebase Console I tried to revoke the public url but it generates a new one. In any case that's not the solution, what I need is **to not upload the files publicly**

Any hint?

The goal of my app is only letting authenticated users access to the storage files.

Comment: You can't do it using Firebase Admin SDK, Firebase Admin SDK bypasses all Storage Rules, you may want to use the [Client SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files) which will use Storage rules that only authenticated users to read and write objects from the Firebase Storage.

Comment: The rules you have laid out say nothing about write permissions, only read. And uploading images is, obviously, a write operation. So based on what you've shown, nothing should prevent the uploading of images through any method. Can you show your entire Storage ruleset?